# how to add button left to cross sign in search view android

Tags: android, searchview

I want this design.

[image]

how to add button left to cross sign ??

Comment: be specific.....

Comment: @DhruvTyagi, I think he wants to add that arrow to the left of *clear* button

Comment: yes right @VladMatvienko...how to do ths??

Comment: I think that it's a custom view there, not the standard searchView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your toolbar.xml, take one imageview and simply add this arrow image, set the margin and you are done.

If you want to make it clickable then do it programatically.